Converting multiple binomial logits to multinomial
I am faced with a image classification problem with 3 classes. My existing network consists of 3 'branches' each corresponding to one of the classes. Each of these branch outputs a binomial logit indicating the likelyhood of the sample belonging/not belonging to the corresponding class. Is there a way I can take these logits, and convert it to a multinomial logit?
From what I understand, essentially my network is currently outputting 3 sets of logits for each of the 3 '1 vs rest' classification. I would like to convert those values to a reasonable representation of a single '1 vs 1 vs 1' classification logit.
From what I read, there are established ways of doing it, but I can't seem to find a suitable resource to guide a beginner like me.
Thanks for your help.
Edit: Added an image for clarity of what I mean. I would like to achieve this without changing the network, but rather processing the output of the network

Can you add a concrete example of what you mean by "branches", "sets of logits", etc. ?

@picky_porpoise added an image for clarity

You could have a look at the way scikit-learn does this in its implementation of the OneVsRestClassifier class: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/872124551/sklearn/multiclass.py#L518
